# VirtualBoxの「保存状態を破棄」の挙動を公式サイトで確認したいです。どこに記載されていますか？

Tags: virtualbox

## 環境

- VirtualBox 7.0.6

## 質問

以下の記事を書くにあたって、「保存状態を破棄」の正確な挙動を理解しておきたいです。
https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/9465a8c7098838990898

`virtualbox 保存状態を破棄`などでGoogle検索しましたが、公式サイトが見つかりませんでした。
公式サイトで、「保存状態を破棄」について記載されている部分を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle VM VirtualBox マネージャーの「ヘルプ」にOnline Documentationがあります。
このドキュメントの[7.22. VBoxManage discardstate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/7.0/user/vboxmanage.html#vboxmanage-discardstate)はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コマンドのヘルプを見ればよかったのですね。解決しました。

Comment: ちなみに、「保存状態の破棄」から"discardstate"コマンドまでは、どのように到達したのでしょうか？
日本語名から英語名を推測したのでしょうか？

Comment: いいえ、ブラウザ(Chrome)で日本語に翻訳されたものを確認しました。※私は英語が不得意です。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。